# My first functional naive neural network in C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network

I just wrote my first standard neural network with SGD gradient descent in c++, I am really interested if I have done anything wrong or inefficient, suggestions would help me a ton
(There is lots of CSV reading/writing code, because I like to plug CSV's to a website which converts CSV to Line graph to see how is my network learning):

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>

#define WEIGHT_RANDOM_RANGE .1

template<typename T>
struct ActivationFunction
{
    std::function<T(T)> activation;
    std::function<T(T)> derivative;
};

template<typename T>
struct ActivationFunctions
{
    inline static const ActivationFunction<T> relu = { [](T x) { return (x > T(0)) ? x : 0; }, [](T x) { return T(x > 0); } };
    inline static const ActivationFunction<T> sigm = { [](T x) { return T(1) / (T(1) + exp(-x)); }, [](T x) { T s = T(1) / (T(1) + exp(-x)); return s * (T(1) - s); } };
    inline static const ActivationFunction<T> tanh = { [](T x) { return std::tanh(x); }, [](T x) { T t = std::tanh(x); return T(1.0f) - t * t; } };
    inline static const ActivationFunction<T> step = { [](T x) { return x <= T(0) ? T(-1) : T(1); }, [](T x) { return 1; } };
    inline static const ActivationFunction<T> none = { [](T x) { return x; }, [](T x) { return 1; } };
};

template<typename T = float>
class NeuralNetwork
{
    using scalar = T;
    using layer = std::vector<scalar>;
    using neuron_layers = std::vector<layer>;
    using batch = neuron_layers;
    using neuron_weights = std::vector<neuron_layers>;
    using size_type = size_t;
public:
    NeuralNetwork(size_type inputs, const std::vector<size_type>& topology, ActivationFunction<scalar> activation = ActivationFunctions<scalar>::relu, scalar learningRate = 0.01f)
        : m_learningRate(learningRate), m_activation(activation)
    {
        //Resize layers to how many layers network will have
        m_neuron_layers.resize(topology.size());
        m_unactivated_neuron_layers.resize(layers_size());
        m_neuron_layer_errors.resize(layers_size());

        m_inputs.resize(inputs);

        for (size_type i = 0; i < topology.size(); ++i)
        {
            m_neuron_layers[i].resize(topology[i]);
            m_unactivated_neuron_layers[i].resize(layer_size(i));
            m_neuron_layer_errors[i].resize(layer_size(i));
        }

        //Initialize weights and resize them according to last layer 
        m_neuron_weights.resize(layers_size());
        srand(time(NULL));
        constexpr scalar weightRandRange = scalar(WEIGHT_RANDOM_RANGE);

        //Initialize input weights
        m_neuron_weights[0].resize(input_layer_size());
        for (size_type j = 0; j < input_layer_size(); ++j)
        {
            m_neuron_weights[0][j].resize(inputs + 1);
            m_neuron_weights[0][j].back() = 0; //Init last weight for each neuron to 0 (because it's a bias)
            for (size_type k = 0; k < inputs; ++k)
            {
                m_neuron_weights[0][j][k] = (scalar(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 2 - 1) * scalar(weightRandRange);
            }
        }

        for (size_type i = 1; i < topology.size(); ++i)
        {
            m_neuron_weights[i].resize(layer_size(i));
            for (size_type j = 0; j < layer_size(i); ++j)
            {
                size_type lastLayerOutputSize = layer_size(i - 1);
                m_neuron_weights[i][j].resize(lastLayerOutputSize + 1);
                m_neuron_weights[i][j].back() = 0;
                for (size_type k = 0; k < lastLayerOutputSize; ++k)
                {
                    m_neuron_weights[i][j][k] = (scalar(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 2 - 1) * scalar(weightRandRange);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    layer forward(const scalar* inputs)
    {
        std::copy(inputs, inputs + input_size(), m_inputs.data());

        for (size_type i = 0; i < input_layer_size(); ++i)
        {
            m_unactivated_neuron_layers[0][i] = std::inner_product(inputs, inputs + input_size(), m_neuron_weights[0][i].data(), m_neuron_weights[0][i][input_size()]);
            m_neuron_layers[0][i] = m_activation.activation(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[0][i]);
        }

        for (size_type i = 1; i < layers_size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_type j = 0; j < layer_size(i); ++j)
            {
                m_unactivated_neuron_layers[i][j] = std::inner_product(m_neuron_layers[i - 1].begin(), m_neuron_layers[i - 1].end(), m_neuron_weights[i][j].begin(), m_neuron_weights[i][j][m_neuron_layers[i - 1].size()]);
                m_neuron_layers[i][j] = m_activation.activation(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return m_neuron_layers.back();
    }
    void backpropagate(const scalar* targets)
    {
        calculateErrors(targets);
        updateWeights();
    }
    void calculateErrors(const scalar* targets)
    {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < output_size(); ++i)
        {
            m_neuron_layer_errors.back()[i] = targets[i] - m_neuron_layers.back()[i];
        }

        for (long i = layers_size() - 2; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            for (size_type j = 0; j < layer_size(i); ++j)
            {
                m_neuron_layer_errors[i][j] = 0;
                for (size_type k = 0; k < layer_size(i + 1); ++k)
                {
                    m_neuron_layer_errors[i][j] += m_neuron_layer_errors[i + 1][k] * m_neuron_weights[i + 1][k][j]; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void updateWeights()
    {
        for (size_type j = 0; j < input_layer_size(); ++j)
        {
            for (size_type k = 0; k < input_size(); ++k)
            {
                m_neuron_weights[0][j][k] += m_learningRate * m_neuron_layer_errors[0][j] * m_activation.derivative(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[0][j]) * m_inputs[k];               
            }
        }

        for (size_type i = 1; i < layers_size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_type j = 0; j < layer_size(i); ++j)
            {
                for (size_type k = 0; k < layer_size(i - 1); ++k)
                {
                    m_neuron_weights[i][j][k] += m_learningRate * m_neuron_layer_errors[i][j] * m_activation.derivative(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[i][j]) * m_neuron_layers[i - 1][k];                 
                }
            }
        }

        //Bias calcs
        for (size_type i = 0; i < layers_size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_type j = 0; j < layer_size(i); ++j)
            {
                m_neuron_weights[i][j].back() += m_learningRate * m_neuron_layer_errors[i][j] * m_activation.derivative(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    void train(const batch inputs, const batch targets, const std::string& learningResultsFilePath = "test_results.csv")
    {
        std::ofstream results(learningResultsFilePath);
        results.clear();
        results << "Errors, Iterations" << std::endl;
        for (size_type i = 0; i < inputs.size(); ++i)
        {
            forward(inputs[i].data());
            backpropagate(targets[i].data());
            if (i % 16 == 0)results << mse() << ',' << i << std::endl;
        }
        results.close();
    }

    //I have 3 CSV files in project folder ("test_in.csv", "test_out.csv", "test_results.csv")
    //test_in is converted to neural network's inputs vector
    //test_out is converted to target vector
    //test_results is for debugging, used to plug it to graphing website
    void train(const std::string& filePath)
    {
        batch inputs;
        batch targets;
        readCSV(filePath + "_in.csv", inputs);
        readCSV(filePath + "_out.csv", targets);
        train(inputs, targets, filePath + "_results.csv");
    }

    void readCSV(const std::string& filePath, batch& data)
    {
        data.clear();
        std::ifstream file(filePath);
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        char* content = new char[file.tellg()];
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        
        std::string line, firstLine;

        size_type index = 0;
        size_type iter = 0;

        std::getline(file, firstLine);
        size_t numInputs = std::count(firstLine.begin(), firstLine.end(), ',') + 1;
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);


        while (std::getline(file, line))
        {
            line = std::move(line) + ',';

            data.emplace_back(numInputs);
            for (size_type j = 0; j < numInputs; ++j)
            {
                size_t found = line.find(',', 0);
                if (found == std::string::npos)continue;
                scalar value = scalar(std::stof(line.substr(0, found)));
                line = line.substr(found + 1, line.size());
                data[iter][j] = value;
            }

            memcpy(content + index, line.data(), (line.size() + 1));
            index += line.size() + 1;
            ++iter;
        }
        file.close();
        delete[] content;
    }

public: //<UTILITIES>//
    inline size_type layers_size() const { return m_neuron_layers.size(); }
    inline size_type layer_size(size_type index) const { return m_neuron_layers[index].size(); }
    inline size_type input_size() const { return m_neuron_weights[0][0].size() - 1; }
    inline size_type input_layer_size() const { return layer_size(0); }
    inline size_type output_size() const { return m_neuron_layers.back().size(); }
    inline scalar mse() const 
    { 
        scalar error = 0; 
        for (size_type i = 0; i < output_size(); ++i)
        {
            error += m_neuron_layer_errors.back()[i] * m_neuron_layer_errors.back()[i];
        }
        return std::sqrt(error / output_size());
    }
public: //<DEBUG>//
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const NeuralNetwork& net)
    {
        os << "Error: " << net.mse();
        return os;
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::ostream_iterator<scalar> carr(std::cout, " | ");
        std::cout << "Network = \n{" << std::endl;

        for (size_type i = 0; i < m_neuron_layers.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << ("    Layer[" + std::to_string(i) + "] = \n    {") << std::endl;
            for (size_type j = 0; j < m_neuron_layers[i].size(); ++j)
            {
                std::cout << ("        Neuron[" + std::to_string(j) + "] = \n        {") << std::endl;
                std::cout << ("            Weights = [ | ");
                std::copy(m_neuron_weights[i][j].begin(), m_neuron_weights[i][j].end() - 1, carr);
                std::cout << "];" << std::endl;
                std::cout << ("            Bias = " + std::to_string(m_neuron_weights[i][j].back()) + ';') << std::endl;
                std::cout << ("            Unactivated_Output = " + std::to_string(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[i][j]) + ';') << std::endl;
                std::cout << ("            Output = " + std::to_string(m_neuron_layers[i][j]) + ';') << std::endl;
                std::cout << ("            Error = " + std::to_string(m_neuron_layer_errors[i][j]) + ';') << std::endl;
                std::cout << "        };" << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << "    }" << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "\n    Outputs = [ | ";
        std::copy(m_neuron_layers.back().data(), m_neuron_layers.back().data() + output_size(), carr);
        std::cout << "];" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    layer m_inputs;
    ActivationFunction<scalar> m_activation;
    neuron_layers m_neuron_layers;
    neuron_layers m_unactivated_neuron_layers;
    neuron_layers m_neuron_layer_errors;
    neuron_weights m_neuron_weights;
    scalar m_learningRate;
};
```

Comment: I could have made actuvation function stuff bit cleaner with virtual classes, but that has  a performance impact (I am pretty sure).

Comment: The use of a pair of function pointers is just fine.  A class containing two named virtual functions would be just the same.  I suppose this way saves one memory access, since the function objects are stored directly rather than in a vtable.

Comment: Is the code working as expected? Asking if something is wrong could lead us to believe the code is broken which would make the question off-topic.

Comment: yes, it's working well. which is pretty suspicious honestly

Comment: "because I like to plug CSV's to a website which converts CSV to Line graph to see how is my network learning". Would you like to share which website that is?

Comment: just google csv to graph, or RawGraphs.io

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#define WEIGHT_RANDOM_RANGE .1`
Don't use `#define` to make your constants.  Use `constexpr`.

In your CSV parser:

```
 scalar value = scalar(std::stof(line.substr(0, found)));
 line = line.substr(found + 1, line.size());
```

That's grossly inefficient.  The `string::substr` creates a new string and copies data.  Then you shorten the input by using `substr` again and assigning back to the line, duplicating, re-duplicating, and then destroying the intermediate copy.

Normally you would scan the string without modifying it by using `iterators`, or a starting index position with the string member functions.

Instead of `stof` (which, BTW, breaks your abstraction of `scalar` and assumes that it is in fact `float`) use `from_chars` which does not require the input to be copied into its own isolated string first.

`line = std::move(line) + ',';`
That's an odd way to append a character to a string.  What's wrong with `push_back`?

`inline size_type layers_size() const { return m_neuron_layers.size(); }`
Good that you use `const` for accessor functions .
But, you don't need to use the `inline` keyword here.  Functions defined inside a class are implicitly inline.

```
for (size_type i = 0; i < output_size(); ++i)
        {
            error += m_neuron_layer_errors.back()[i] * m_neuron_layer_errors.back()[i];
        }
```

You're repeatedly calling `m_neuron_layer_errors.back()`, when it doesn't change within the loop let alone within the expression!  You're also subscripting it with the same value more than once.

You seem to be iterating over all the elements in a `vector`.  So don't use a counting loop!  Just iterate over the vector directly.

```
for (const auto x : m_neuron_layer_errors.back())
    error += x*x;
```

You can apply this idea in *many* loops in your code.

---

Your function defined:    `layer forward(const scalar* inputs)`
will return a **copy** of an entire vector.

You then call it: `forward(inputs[i].data());` throwing away the return value.  This is pointless and inefficient.

Comment: wow, thanks this is very helpful

Comment: `x` is a `float` (scalar type), right?  So making a reference to it would be slower than copying the value.  It's probably going to be held in a vector register ready for use in the math!

Comment: (can't upvote) even for your own questions?  (It's been a long time since I was `new` to Stack Overflow)

Comment: yup you can't upvote, it requires 15 reputation, also yes x is float completly forgot about that.

Comment: I can upvote now thanks to this question, I am deleting old comments

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> #include <math.h>
> ```

Prefer to include `<cmath>`.  That's better, as it declares its identifiers in the `std` namespace.  We'll need to change `exp()` to `std::exp()`, but OTOH, `std::tanh()` becomes correct.

We're missing

- `<cstring>`, for `std::memcpy()`
- `<iterator>`, for `std::ostream_iterator`

`std::size_t` is misspelt in several places.

> ```
> template<typename T>
> struct ActivationFunctions
> {
>     inline static const ActivationFunction<T> relu = { [](T x) { return (x > T(0)) ? x : 0; }, [](T x) { return T(x > 0); } };
>     inline static const ActivationFunction<T> sigm = { [](T x) { return T(1) / (T(1) + exp(-x)); }, [](T x) { T s = T(1) / (T(1) + exp(-x)); return s * (T(1) - s); } };
>     inline static const ActivationFunction<T> tanh = { [](T x) { return std::tanh(x); }, [](T x) { T t = std::tanh(x); return T(1.0f) - t * t; } };
>     inline static const ActivationFunction<T> step = { [](T x) { return x <= T(0) ? T(-1) : T(1); }, [](T x) { return 1; } };
>     inline static const ActivationFunction<T> none = { [](T x) { return x; }, [](T x) { return 1; } };
> };
> ```

Constant classes are an anti-pattern, and usually best replaced with functions, perhaps in a namespace.  Like this (with newlines - notice how that makes them more readable?):

```
namespace ActivationFunctions
{
    template<typename T>
    constexpr ActivationFunction<T> relu = {
        [](T x) { return (x > T(0)) ? x : 0; },
        [](T x) { return T(x > 0); }
    };
    template<typename T>
    constexpr ActivationFunction<T> sigm = {
        [](T x) { return T(1) / (T(1) + std::exp(-x)); },
        [](T x) { T s = T(1) / (T(1) + std::exp(-x)); return s * (T(1) - s); }
    };
    template<typename T>
    constexpr ActivationFunction<T> tanh = {
        [](T x) { return std::tanh(x); },
        [](T x) { T t = std::tanh(x); return T(1.0f) - t * t; }
    };
    template<typename T>
    constexpr ActivationFunction<T> step = {
        [](T x) { return x <= T(0) ? T(-1) : T(1); },
        [](T x) { return 1; }
    };
    template<typename T>
    constexpr ActivationFunction<T> none = {
        [](T x) { return x; },
        [](T x) { return 1; }
    };
}
```

Obviously, that changes how we identify them:

```
NeuralNetwork(size_type inputs, const std::vector<size_type>& topology,
              ActivationFunction<scalar> activation = ActivationFunctions::relu<scalar>,
              scalar learningRate = 0.01f)
```

I think we might do better if we help the compiler to inline these functions, by making them part of the `NeuralNetwork<T>` class.  We can do that by inheriting them as a base class (using the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern):

```
namespace ActivationFunctions
{
    template<typename T>
    struct relu {
        static constexpr auto activation(T x) { return (x > T(0)) ? x : T(0); }
        static constexpr auto derivative(T x) { return T(x > 0); }
    };
    ⋮
}
```

```
template<typename T = float,
         template<typename> class AF = ActivationFunctions::relu>
class NeuralNetwork : AF<T>
```

We then remove the `m_activation` member, and just call the functions through the (implicit) `this` pointer.  E.g. `m_activation.activation(…)` becomes simply `activation(…)`.

Obviously this route makes it more difficult to select an activation function at runtime; without the calling code, it's impossible to say whether that's an obstacle to be overcome.

The `print()` function unnecessarily flushes output (with `std::endl`) much more than necessary.  I would replace all of those with ordinary non-flushing newline, `'\n'`.

Comment: I used to use namespaces for every function instead of static classes or such, when I was newcomer from java, is it bad to do so, if so what should I use?

Comment: thanks for suggestions.

Comment: I dont think std::function<T> can be constexpr, can it?

Comment: GCC didn't complain - but I never instantiated the `NeuralNetwork`, because there's no `main()`.

Comment: Having instantiated, I now get the error for the constexpr.  But these are pure functions, so perhaps `std::function` is overkill anyway?

Comment: I tried using naive function pointers, but it got much worse performance for some reason.

Comment: I think the way to improve performance is to provide inlineable functions, probably using CRTP.  I'll think on that and perhaps add a suggestion.

Comment: I've updated showing how to use CRTP (assuming that compile-time selection of function is acceptable; there's a bit more work involved to allow run-time choice).

Answer (score 2):

#### Loops

You criminally underuse the [range-based for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).  JDlogusz already mentioned this, but it cannot be said enough.  Avoid index variables whenever possible.

#### Memory management

```
char* content = new char[file.tellg()];
//...
delete[] content;
```

[`new` and `delete` are code smells.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49678836/4926165)  The *only* acceptable times for manual memory management in C++ are when you are writing your own smart pointers or allocators.  Otherwise, use [the STL smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).  For example:

```
//Avoid new entirely
auto content{std::make_unique<char[]>(file.tellg())};
//Use new, but let compiler handle lifetime
//(dangerous! --- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22571331/4926165)
std::unique_ptr<char[]> content(new char[file.tellg()]);
//For a raw pointer:
char *ptr{content.get()};

//Container classes also function as smart pointers
std::vector<char[]> content(file.tellg());
char *ptr{content.data()};
std::string content('\0xF', file.tellg());
char *ptr{content.c_str()};
```

#### Randomness

`rand` is [very rarely](https://web.archive.org/web/20180801210127/http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx) the correct randomness engine for your needs.  Most implementations are very poor and it is hard to turn `rand`'s output into useful values; see [STL's presentation](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).  Consider using [C++'s pseudo-random number libraries](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead.

#### Functors

```
ActivationFunction<scalar> m_activation;
```

`std::function` has very high overhead.  Are you really likely to be changing which activation function you use based on user input?  If not, you can determine it at compile time.  Consider passing a Functor object as type parameter to your class, like so:

```
struct relu
{
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(T input) const noexcept {return std::max<T>(input, 0);}
    struct deriv_t {
        template<typename T>
        auto operator()(T input) const noexcept {return T(input > 0);}
    } derivative;
};
template<typename Scalar = float, typename Activation = relu>
class NeuralNetwork
{
    //...
    m_neuron_layers[0][i] = activation(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[0][i]);
    //...
    m_neuron_weights[0][j][k] += m_learningRate * m_neuron_layer_errors[0][j] * m_activation.derivative(m_unactivated_neuron_layers[0][j]) * m_inputs[k];
    //...
    Activation m_activation;
}
```

Moreover, why are you separating out the function and its derivative?  C++ supports operator overloading.  Consider using [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) instead.

#### Separating out test code

```
void train(const batch inputs, const batch targets, const std::string& learningResultsFilePath = "test_results.csv");
```

Why are you hardcoding that output should go to a file?  Instead, consider taking an [output stream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) or even an output iterator (courtesy of [`ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)).

```
    void NeuralNetwork::train(const std::string& filePath);
    void NeuralNetwork::readCSV(const std::string& filePath, batch& data);
```

Why are these in `NeuralNetwork`?  Not everything has to be in a class; not everything has to be in the *same* class.  Consider putting NeuralNetwork inside a namespace (say, `nn`), and then these functions inside `nn` or `nn::Test`.

```
public: //<DEBUG>//
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const NeuralNetwork& net);
    void print();
```

If these functions are debug-only, why aren't they only compiled in debug mode?  For example (MSVS):

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
public: //<DEBUG>//
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const NeuralNetwork& net);
    void print();
#endif
```

#### Parsing

```
for (size_type j = 0; j < numInputs; ++j)
{
    size_t found = line.find(',', 0);
    if (found == std::string::npos)continue;
    scalar value = scalar(std::stof(line.substr(0, found)));
    line = line.substr(found + 1, line.size());
    data[iter][j] = value;
}
```

This parsing code is brittle.  Consider using a state machine or [`stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) instead:

```
{
    std::istringstream line_{line};
    scalar value;
    char delim;
    while(line_ >> value >> delim)
    {
        assert(','==delim);
        data[iter].emplace_back(std::move(value));
    }
}
```

(Yes, the `std::move` is probably overkill, but better safe than sorry….)

Also, you again should consider a design that accepts arbitrary stream/iterator inputs.  That seeking and telling at the beginning of `readCSV` is a major code smell to me.

#### Function Signatures

```
void readCSV(const std::string& filePath, batch& data);
```

What do you have against return values?

```
batch readCSV(const std::string &filePath);
```

None of your private functions return a value.  That suggests to me that they probably keep too much information in the state of your neural network.  (It should end up there eventually, don't get me wrong!  Just I would expect calling code to do the assignments:

```
m_neuron_layers = forward(inputs.data())
```

Of course, if you aren't changing all the values in `m_neuron_layers` or want to avoid memory allocations, then maybe this makes sense.)

Comment: ReadCSV is a code smell I know, I got rid of it, because I don't need to actually write everything to file, not sure what made me think that, but good thing I left it here, now am getting lots of tips I did not know

Comment: Rand() should be fine tho, I don't think it will cause any problems in my case, thanks for the detailed review.